# Is it possible to post an SMTP HTML email with forms controls to a web page?

Tags: asp.net, email

I thought I'd ask before I try.

I'm guessing that I need to have something monitor an email inbox to process the emails rather than submitting them directly to a web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think "submitting them directly to a web page" is possible, unless I'm misunderstanding.  Probably, the flow will be:

User email->Server inbox->Database->Generated HTML

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am thinking, too.Thanks.